# How to avoid npm install/update surprises?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, devops

How to safely npm install/update when deploying/upgrading ?

- **Problem 1 :** `npm install` is a statefull operation that depends on the latest versions of dependencies in the time when the command is executed. This causes surprises when deploying since `package.json` file indicates ranges but not specific versions.
- **Problem 2 :** everytime I make `npm update` or use `ncu`, I spend hours/days trying to handle incoherences between modules. Why would this happens in 2018 ?
- **Problem 3 :** How to have `package.json` file that describes exactly the state of installed packages instead of ranges so that I can deploy without surprises ?

**NB:** I use Angular

Answer (score 7):

If you use `yarn` or a more recent version of `npm`, it will generate for you a `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`.

This will keep exactly the version of any package when it's first installed, so further calls to `yarn` or `npm install` will fetch and install exactly those versions.

Of course you should **add these lock files to your repository** so anyone doing a fresh clone get the same dependencies installed.

See the npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

And the yarn docs: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/

Comment: npm is modifying the package-lock during install in my case and changing the version numbers.

Comment: Same for me, npm updates the package-lock.json when doing `npm i`, is there a way to install things as-it, without updating any dep? I'm installing an open source project which doesn't use fixed version, and I don't want to update those deps.

Answer (score 1):

1. `package.json file indicates ranges but not specific versions` : Re-read the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies), you *can* specify specific versions. See point 3 for an example.
2. `Why would this happens in 2018` <= I/we can't speculate as to problems where you did not include any specific details, it might be a valid general gripe you have but StackOverflow is not the correct place to vent it.
3. Again, see the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies). You just have to include the version number with an `=` sign. Example below would get only the version `5.0.0` of `@angular/cdk`.

   ```
   "@angular/cdk": "5.0.0"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

be advised that any call to `npm update` will update your `package.json` with the latest *minor* version, so setting a strict constraint version ex (`5.0.0`) will only work with `npm install` when no `package-lock.json` is present. When doing npm update, your `5.0.0` constraint will be replaced by a `^5.5.0` constraint (or whatever the next minor release is). It's fine if the packages you are using implement semver correctly, but you can have a lot of issues with breaking changes on minor release.